# How to format phone number in grid column in ext

Tags: extjs4.1, phone-number

I am trying to format phone numbers in grid column from 1234567890 to 123-456-7890. I tried something of this sort to do...

```
renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d')
```

but obviously this only works for date. Is there a way to render phone numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who need it, here's the solution for phone number

```
 renderer: function (value) {
                    return value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, '$1-$2-$3');}
```